# I'm curious about how @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) works in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

Sorry for using a translator, but I'm not familiar with English, so there may be some awkward sentences.
In Jackson, if JsonInclude is set to NonNull, if the value of the field is null, the form of the Json on serialise will be missing the key with null value, and I was wondering how Jackson Library works.

Eventually, it seems that ObjectMapper's writeValueAsString will find the nonNull value and exclude the field, but I couldn't find the process of finding and removing the annotation, so I was wondering how that works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove the functionality of ignoring keys with null values, then there are are 3 different places you need to look for the configuration (annotation or constructor parameter):

1. The annotation may be at the class level and you would need to remove that annotation:

```java
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  
    class Foo {
```

2. The annotation may be at the field level and you would need to remove that annotation:

```java
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)  
    public String foo;
```

3. Or it may be set globally with the ObjectMapper constructor.  If that is the case you would need to remove the parameter from the constructor:

```java
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

If asking how the annotation works, The annotation functions as a filtering mechanism as the jackson library is serializing objects.  One key thing to keep in mind is that the determination of inclusion/exclusion is based on Java value.  This comes into play if you are dealing with container objects.  For example a Map, if the Map instance is null it would be excluded, however a Map that is empty or a Map with only with null values would still be included.  The annotation does allow you to specify both a value attribute and a content attribute to help fine tune how a container object is handled

```
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY,
     content = JsonInclude.INCLUDE_NON_NULL)
```

So this would include a non null Map that has at least one value.  The content (map entries) would then be further filtered to only include entry values that are not null.

Comment: The question was "how does the annotation work?", not "how can I enable the annotation?"

Comment: I added some additional details in my original response.  I hope that helps.  Geel free to ask some more specific questions on how it works.

Comment: I guess this is a bit off-topic, as I was wondering about how the Jackson core library recognizes nulls in `@JsonInclude` and how the **null value field** disappears during the serialization process. Could you please explain if you can? It would also be very helpful if you could point me to the method in your code that does that behavior for Jackson Library